# Unexpected uncontrollable double integrator system during reference tracking (augmented state-space)

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I'm trying to design a controller that will achieve reference tracking of the *second* state for the following system.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} &=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]}_A x+\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]}_B u \\
y &=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]}_C x
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$x=\left[\begin{array}{l}
q \\
\dot{q}
\end{array}\right]
$$
This problem should be equivalent to tracking a ramp on the first state, hence we require a type-2 system if we are to achieve zero steady-state error. Therefore, we require a double integrator to augment the system with the integrals of the error between the reference and performance output. The error $e$, reference $r$ (step) and performance matric $H = \left[\begin{array}{l}
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ are related as
$$e=r-Hx$$
If $e=0$, the reference is tracked with zero steady-state error. The system can be augmented by adding states $\int e$ and $\int \int e$, with dynamics
$$\dot{w}=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{l}
0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]}_Mw+\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\ 0
\end{array}\right]}_Ne$$
where
$$w=\left[\begin{array}{l}
\int e \\ \int \int e
\end{array}\right]$$
The augmented system is then given by
$$\left[\begin{array}{l}
\dot{x} \\ \dot{w}
\end{array}\right]=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{l}
A & 0_{2 \times 2}\\ -NH & M
\end{array}\right]}_{A_e}\left[\begin{array}{l}
x \\ w
\end{array}\right]+\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{l}
B \\ 0_{2 \times 1}
\end{array}\right]}_{B_e}u+\left[\begin{array}{l}
0_{2 \times 1} \\ N
\end{array}\right]r$$
**My question:** strangely enough, the pair $(A_e,B_e)$ is uncontrollable for the provided matrices, but it is controllable when I change to $H = \left[\begin{array}{l}
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]$. After designing a controller, it can track a ramp on the state $q$, which implies tracking a step on $\dot{q}$, but I feel that the former $H$ should yield identical behaviour when a step $r$ is applied to track $\dot{q}$. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: .  .  .  .  .  . . .

Comment: I ought to be able answer his but have forgotten my learning on matrices, sadly

Comment: The goal is the state $x_2$ to track a step input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uncontrollability makes sense, because the first error integral will be a shifted version of $q$, hence we cannot control them independently.